# Write a maximum of two instructions to clear, set and complement some bits in the AL register

Tags: assembly, x86, xor, masm

**You are required to write a maximum of two instructions in assembly to do the following:**

1. Clear bits 0 and 7 of register AL, i.e. make them 0
2. Set bits 3 and 4 of register AL, i.e. make them 1.
3. Complement bits 1 and 5 of register AL.
4. Keep all other bits in the register AL as is without changing their values.

Comment: The ***three*** instruction solution: `al -> al & 0b01111110 | 0b00011000 ^ 0b00100010`. The hard part is reduce this to 2 instructions.

Comment: Well it's a bonus question. i don't have to give an answer for it but i kept thinking of the solution and i'm still thinking

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick here is to do the following:

1. use an OR instruction to *set* bits 0, 3, 4 and 7
2. use an XOR instruction to *complement* bits 0, 1, 5 and 7

Note that bits 0 and 7 first get set in (1) and then cleared in (2).

I'll leave the actual asm instructions to you, since this is your homework, after all.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Paul. This should be the code:

OR AL, 10011001
XOR AL, 10100011

Comment: @Nick: yes, that looks about right, depending on exactly what CPU and assembler you're using.

Comment: another way is clearing bit 0, 3, 4, 7 then complementing bit 1, 3, 4, 5. [Clang can do this optimization](https://godbolt.org/g/yan2Kr)

Answer (score 4):

One DB instruction defining an array of 256 "result" values, and one move instruction to move an element of this array into al, using the current value in al as an index.

Wouldn't that work ?

It might even be argued that this is in fact even a single-instruction solution, since the DB is not really an instruction that executes at run-time, rather it is a compile-time declarative.

Comment: He's proposing a lookup table with a result value for each of the 256 possible input values. The list is created using the DB command. Lookup is performed using a simple `move AL, start + index` instruction.